# How to use golang reflections to modify a slice of structs?

Tags: go, reflection, slice

How to use the golang reflect API to append to a slice of structs, where the struct itself isn't known and user-defined?

I've tried to use various ways of getting the "type of the struct" from the pointer to the slice, but I don't know which API to use. If the slice of structs itself is empty, there will be an index out of range error.

In the example code, the line 25 is commented and doesn't work. What should I use instead?

```golang
package main

import "errors"
import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type MyStruct struct {
    StringExample string `mytag:"string"`
}

func appendTo(object any) error {

    valueof := reflect.ValueOf(object)

    if valueof.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return errors.New("ptr required")
    }

    valueof = valueof.Elem()
    valueof_kind := valueof.Kind()

    if valueof_kind == reflect.Slice {

        // XXX: This does not work, slice is empty
        the_unknown_type := reflect.TypeOf(valueof.Index(0))

        the_struct := reflect.New(the_unknown_type)
        the_struct.Field(0).SetString("test")

        valueof.Set(reflect.Append(valueof, the_struct))

    } else if valueof_kind == reflect.Struct {
        // ...
    }

    return nil

}

func main() {

    var myslice []MyStruct

    appendTo(&myslice)
    appendTo(&myslice)

    fmt.Println(myslice)

}
```

I tried to use `reflect.ValueOf(object).Type()` and `reflect.Value.Kind()`, but I don't understand how to get the type of the slice "cells".

Comment: Use Elem(). As you already know Elem() dereferences, but it also gives you the "element type" of a slice type. I.e. `the_slice_elem_type := valueof.Type().Elem()`

Comment: Alternatively: `the_type_of_0th_elem := valueof.Index(0).Type()`

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/NPrGbeR8Kq1